# Compiling MEX files in Matlab 32bit running on Windows 64bit

Tags: matlab

What is the right setup to do this?

Currently when I enter `mex -setup`, the compiler list is empty.
I installed Visual C++ Express 2008 and Windows SDK, but the supported compilers list is still empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually configure the `mexopts.bat` file, so that your compiler is identified by the `mex` command. Here there is an example `mexopts.bat` file: http://www.playrec.co.uk/download/mexopts.bat - be sure to edit it to fit your system settings (path etc.). Also, you should put this file in the current folder when you compile the code, otherwise Matlab will use its default file.

Comment: What should be done differently from the file generated by `mex -setup`)? Is there a limitation on the compilers I can use?

Comment: The difference is that `mex -setup` does not recognize your compiler, so you have to configure it manually. I don't know of any limitations, but the toolchain you use (compiler, linker etc.) should recognize the options sent to them by Matlab.